# after moving the asp.net app from IIS 6 to IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2 IIS 7 is not allowing to save the doc/execl files locally

Tags: asp.net, iis

we have recently moved one of our ASP.Net app from IIS 6 windows server 2003 to IIS 7 windows server 2008 R2. when the application was in IIS 6 we were able to bowose that and able to save the doc/excel files locally. But after moving that to  IIS 7 on windows server 2008 R2 we can browse that app but not able to save the doc/execl locally.

could anyone please help me on this.

Thanks and Regards,

krishnamurthy

Comment: hi All,

now i am getting below error.

Error: An unexpected error has occurred while locally saving the requested file. Error details - Word cannot open the document: user does not have access privileges (C:\Document\0667-DP-13-0007865-A.doc) at GetFile.SaveLocalCopy(Object filePath) in c:\Proposal\GetFile.aspx.cs:line 146 at GetFile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Proposal\GetFile.aspx.cs:line 30

please help me on this.

Comment: Make sure your Application Pool has sufficient permissions to access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which user the application pool for your site is running as. This could be:

`ApplicationPoolIdentity`, `NetworkService` or another specified user.

If you change the app pool to use `NetworkService` you will then be able to assign security permissions on your directory allowing `NetworkService` read / modify permissions.

See this link for more information: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx